# Can you use an onClick right after declaring an id to an element

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make a Tic Tac Toe program and I had a question about id's and onClicks. My question is: Can you use an onClick right after declaring an id to an element. What I mean is this.

```html
<td id="t1" onClick='t1'></td>
```

Because what I want to do is make it when you click that cell, an X appears in that cell, and I would write that for the other nine cells.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It'd be a lot easier.

Comment: `onClick='t1'` – what is that supposed to achieve? Doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: Can't use jQuery because it is a small lab. also Cbroe im still learning and it was an example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would do something like this

```
<td id="t1" onclick="this.innerHTML = "X">
```

or you could use this.innerText, but that should do it.

Comment: This would work too depending on how you want the "x" to appear.

Answer (score 0):

use background images instead of colors, could do with a bit of styling

```js
var per1="1";
var cells=document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0;i < cells.length;i++){
      cells[i].addEventListener('click',function(){addGO(this);
                                                  }
                                )};
  
function addGO(theCell){
  var j=theCell;
  if(per1 == "1"){
    //alert('1');
    j.className +="person1"; per1="0";
    }
  else
    {j.className +="person2";per1="1";}
    
  }
```

```css
td{width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid black;}
.person1{background-color:red;}
.person2{background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<table >
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
 </table>
```